# Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT set Button location on MapControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I want to set the Button on MapControl in my WP 8.1 app. The problem is the Button isn't on location of the element only is on top-left of the Map and it is moving. Location in binding is Geopoint. Here's my code:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="MapEvent" Grid.Row="1">

        <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" 
                                Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5" 
    Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>

    </Maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: 1) Do you have  a single button, or many buttons = 1 button per DataItem ? Have you got a WinRT WP 8.1 app or a Silverlight WP8.1 app - in other terms do you use Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.MapControl or Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map ?

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN I have many buttons in Observablecollection. It's works and buttons appear but they aren't on their positions on the map. I use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl  and WinRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt of some code working for me :

```
public class PhotoInfo
{
    public String Label { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public Geocoordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
    public Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get { return new Point(0.5, 1); } }
}
```

I just reminded that one should not bind on `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geocoordinate` but on `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint`.

This is why Binding of `m:MapControl.Location` is on `Coordinate.Point`

```
<m:MapControl ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel}" Center="{Binding Center}"  MapServiceToken="xxx">
    <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoInfos}">
        <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image m:MapControl.Location="{Binding Coordinate.Point}" 
                                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/pushpin.png" 
                               m:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NormalizedAnchorPoint}" Width="20" Height="45" Tapped="Image_Tapped"/> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </m:MapItemsControl>
</m:MapControl>
```

Comment: Sorry I poorly explained. This buttons represent objects in Observablecollection on the map. Every object has a location which is set on the map. Result of this code is buttons are on the map. They have content names but aren't on their location and they "hang" on the map. Location isn't null etc.

Comment: I need to be sure that ObservableCollection that is the DataContext of your MapControl. But it would be better if the Collection would be a property of the object that is in the ViewModel. That property would be called 'Locations' for instance and you 'd write  <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">

Comment: so in my viewmodel I have ObservableCollection. I create static object of vm in App.xaml.cs. In View in onNavigatedTo method I load data from json to Observablecollection and I have: this.DataContext = "my_OC";

Comment: @Quiet, so from what I see,your binding seems pretty good. I just totally changed my answer, because I had another idea of a problem I had that could be yours

Comment: I added Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location.Point } but still is the same. I see you have Geocoordinate type. It's should be that? I don't know what create this type.

Comment: I just edited my post to show exat types of coordinates.

Comment: Sorry for question bombing and asking same question :  Have you got a WinRT WP 8.1 app or a Silverlight WP8.1 app - in other terms do you use Windows.UI.Xaml.Maps.MapControl or Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map ?

Comment: I have WinRT WP 8.1 app not Silverlight. I use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl. I don't know what's going on because this buttons display on map with their names from my bind but no location.

Comment: I think if Location is not used it is because the data you provide for location is incorrect.

Comment: To me if you ve got Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl, it is WinRT

Comment: You should try to make your Location property type to match what I provided. I get my Geocoordinates from the GPS

Comment: My Location is Geopoint type and it's correct because I use this to set pushpin in other view and this works. Can I ask you how do I create this Geocoordinates obj when I have Longitude and Latitude? I don't know how as it should be.

Comment: Sure.I get it from GPS. But you could give a try with dummy/hardcoded data. Geolocator geo = new Geolocator(); Geoposition position = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync(); Geocoordinate coordinate = position.Coordinate; I think you can get it  from the last intruction without GPS. Hold on. We 'll get it !  :-)

Comment: Okay I tried this with GPS and it looks like it's the same problem all the time :( I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Actually I think you don't have to use GPS coordinates. If you ve got a Geopoint, you can call the Coordinate property to get a Geocoordinate

Comment: YES! It's work. You're right. My problem was that when I navigate to view with the map, task with coordinates won't finished. I add few seconds before navigate and it's run! Now, I have to rewrite my code. I'm very grateful. It was my stupid fault. Thank you! You're GREAT!

Comment: I have last question. It's any simple way to create Geocoordinate? Now I get this from GPS but I need this with longitude and latitude from my objects. Getting first this from GPS is waste of time.

Comment: Great ! We share the same joy. Remove "stupid fault" please. You don't have to be guilty.

Comment: Maybe it could be another StackOverflow question ...?

Comment: Right. This is new topic if you want help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639477/c-sharp-windows-phone-8-1-how-to-get-geocoordinate-object