# c# Windows Phone 8.1 How to get Geocoordinate object

Tags: c#, gps, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I need to get Geocoordinate object with my Longitude and Latitude. Cannot get Geocoordinates by new()
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate
One way is for example this code

```
var locator = new Geolocator();
        locator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
        var position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate Coordinate = position.Coordinate;
```

Which gets GPS coordinate. But I need Geocoordinate with my Longitude and Latitude.

Comment: It's a sealed class with no public constructors, so you can't.  Why do you need one?

Comment: @PaulAbbott I want to set on MapControl pushpins. Only Geocoordinate works in xaml binding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616665/windows-phone-8-1-winrt-set-button-location-on-mapcontrol

Comment: MapIcons and XAML controls use `Geopoint` to establish location on a map.  What do you mean "Only Geocoordinate works in xaml binding"?  The question you linked even says "one should not bind on `Geocoordinate` but on `Geopoint`".

Comment: @PaulAbbott Fine, but when I have object Geopoint Location, then Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location.Position}" not works. When I have Geoocordinate Location then Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location.Point}" works very well. How do I do that using Geopoint?

Comment: If `Location` is a `Geopoint`, then you want `Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"`.  `Location.Position` is a `BasicGeoposition`, which is not what the map control wants.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Oh, it's works :) Please answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `Geocoordinate` since it is a sealed, read-only class.  Instead, bind to a `Geopoint`, which contains all the location info you need without the location service baggage that `Geocoordinate` has.

`public Geopoint Location { get; set; }`

`Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"`